# How do you disable ReSharper for a VS.net solution?

Tags: resharper

Is it possible to disable ReSharper from running for a given vs.net solution?

Comment: Windows >> Run utility >>`devenv /SafeMode`. It won't run for current vs instance.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the Resharper Menu -> Options -> Settings -> Advanced -> Add your Solution Folder

That'll set it to ignore all files and folders in that location.

Comment: That will only ignore the files for code analysis, the intellisense still processes the files.

Answer (score 7):

If you start VS with the /safemode flag it disables resharper. I just had to do that then, we have a project with 241 MB of generated code (don't ask!) and that was the only way I could coax VS2008 to link it without bailing.

Comment: devenv.exe /safemode (in windows run menu for VS2013 tested)

Answer (score 2):

This thread may help you: http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/213878